# How to check if a list of points contain only one polygon or have other polygons inside

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geometry, polygon

I have a list of some points (x,y) that was made by merging a bunch of 1x1 squares together. This list represents corner points of this one merged polygon.

I made an algorithm to sort these points into a chain to draw a polygon, for example like this:

[image: normal polygon]

But my algorithm have a big problem - it can't account for times when this polygon have holes in it like that:

[image: polygon with holes]

My algorithm works by taking the lowest, most left point and then finding closest point to it on horizontal axix. Then for this point it finds the closest vertical point, then for that one closest horizontal again and so on, and so on.
There is also a check if the closest found point is not behind some other point we already went through. It works if all of the points are on the outside part of a polygon

So, my question is - **how can I detect from a list of (unsorted)points that my polygon has holes(other polygons) in it?**
I write in kotlin, but I'm mainly interested in algorithm itself

Comment: If it is made of 1x1 squares, then fill a corresponding matrix with a 1 for a 1x1 square. Then search for 0 inside and with neighbors all 1.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That won’t always work. Imagine a 2x2 gap inside of a figure.

Comment: It's not generally possible to determine which squares were filled from a list of the corners.  For example, make an X and list the corners.  Then remove the center filled square and list the corners.  It's the same list.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Excellent point. I had assumed (?) the OP’s question was of the form “I have the corner points of a single enclosing polygon and want to determine whether it has a hole.” But if the question is “I have the corner points of _every_ enclosing polygon,” this gets a lot harder. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one way to do this. Imagine tracing the outline of the polygon. If the polygon has no holes, then this trace should pass through all the corner points. If the polygon has a hole, then there will be some corner points not touched this way. So basically all we need to do is find a way to start at a point and walk around the perimeter of the polygon, tracking which points we encounter, and then see whether we got them all.

To do this, sort the points from top to bottom by y coordinate, then take the leftmost point with the highest y coordinate. Initialize a direction vector that points to the right (e.g. dx = 1, dy = 0). Then follow the “right-hand rule:” if you can take a step forward (e.g. moving by (dx, dy) doesn’t pass through a solid barrier) and in doing so your right hand stays on the polygon (e.g. there’s an edge of the polygon running from your current position to the next position), walk forward one step. Otherwise turn to the left and try this again.

As you do this, keep track of all the corner points you visit. Once you’re back to where you started, compare those corner points against your master list of points and see what you came up with. If you touched all the corner points there are no holes, otherwise there’s a hole.

Comment: Do we know where the edges are? I think we just have points, in which case this can fail by assuming an edge which doesn't exist.

Comment: We can recover the edges by looking at adjacent pairs of y-vals per x-val & vice versa, then this works.

Comment: I assumed (?) we have access to the underlying grid that the squares came from, or alternatively that the points are already joined into polygon boundaries. But I agree that if we don’t have that then this approach won’t work.